# how to check two values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql.

I would like to check two values in my `users` table.

```
$same_user = "mfalse" ;

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$email' OR phone='$phone'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)
        {
            $same_user = "mfalse" ;
        }
        else
        {
            $same_user = "mtrue" ;
            mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
            mysql_query("insert into users (username,pass,fname,lname,phone,city)
              VALUES  (N'$email',N'$pass',N'$fname',N'$lname',N'$phone',N'$city')");
        }


        $arr = array(
        'sameuser'=>$same_user);

    return $arr ;
```

in the above my code, the inserted occurs but from `$arr` I get :

> {"sameuser":"mfalse"}

why ?

---

**updated**

My function :

```
function regiterAnUser($an_user){
    //email,pass,fname,lname,phone,city
    $content    = explode("-",$an_user);
    $email      = $content[0];
    $pass       = $content[1];
    $fname      = $content[2];
    $lname      = $content[3];
    $phone      = $content[4];
    $city       = $content[5];

    $pass = md5($pass);


    $same_user = "mfalse" ;

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$email' OR phone='$phone'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)
    {
        $same_user = "mfalse" ;
    }
    else
    {
        $same_user = "mtrue" ;
        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        mysql_query("insert into users (username,pass,fname,lname,phone,city)
          VALUES  (N'$email',N'$pass',N'$fname',N'$lname',N'$phone',N'$city')");
    }


    $arr = array(
        'sameuser'=>$same_user);

    return $arr ;
}
```

Comment: You mean that insertion occurs (which is in else ) as well as mfalse (which is in if) are u pasting exact code ?

Comment: Yes, my question updated.

Comment: What is it giving if u change first $same_user to '1' second to '2' and third to '3' ? Comment here

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You're potentially open to SQL injection attacks (depending on where those "parameters" come from) and why aren't you passing the parameters in as parameters? An email address of *fred-bloggs@example.com* (for instance) will completely break your code. `md5` should never be used for *securing* a password... and so on. Honestly, I'd start over on this with some PHP/MySQL sites/books to hand.

Comment: I'm guessing the phone number isn't mandatory and that a record already exists with a phone number of `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

I would no use `mysql` function but, it is your choice.

I refactored your code and it works for me, please let me know

```
function regiterAnUser($an_user){
    $same_user = "mfalse" ;
    //email,pass,fname,lname,phone,city
    $content    = explode("-",$an_user);
    $email      = mysql_real_escape_string($content[0]);
    $pass       = mysql_real_escape_string($content[1]);
    $fname      = mysql_real_escape_string($content[2]);
    $lname      = mysql_real_escape_string($content[3]);
    $phone      = mysql_real_escape_string($content[4]);
    $city       = mysql_real_escape_string($content[5]);
    $pass = md5($pass);

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$email' OR phone='$phone'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)<1) {
        $same_user = "mtrue" ;
        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        mysql_query("insert into users (username,pass,fname,lname,phone,city)
          VALUES  (N'$email',N'$pass',N'$fname',N'$lname',N'$phone',N'$city')");
    }

    return array('sameuser'=>$same_user) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to output `$sql`?

Anyway I would recommend to count the rows with MySQL. Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

And please don't use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) for example.